# How do I specify a file on my HDD in XMLHttpRequest.open("GET", file.txt, true)?

Tags: ajax

I have tried:

```
[This is not a link](http://localhost/file.txt)
```

Which did not work. What exactly am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `file` protocol, but then you'd need to spell out the full path.  (To see an example, open a local file from the browser.)

Unless you actually have an HTTP server running on your machine, and it is serving the file you want, the URL you're using won't work.